# How to access the object value with java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator type

Tags: java

I need to access the value for the field called this$0 of object type java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator type, see the image below.

the object

```
Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> ite = data.getFields();
```

[image]

as you can see, I have a object "ite" and I need to access the value of field "this$0" , how to get it?

Comment: Isn't that the original `LinkedHashMap` from which the `Iterator` came?

Comment: `this$0` looks like a `Map`.

Comment: This field is connection between inner type instance, and its outer type instance. In case of our example it will represent `LinkedHashMap` on which was created instance of inner `EntryIterator`. Anyway do you want to get access to it in debugger/at runtime/while unit tests?

Comment: share the code as well and let us know what do you want to get?

Comment: @Pshemo I just have the "ite" object, I want to get the value of "this$0" field, so the "{Version=0, name="RODRIGO RODRIGUES"" etc... that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This field is added by compiler to store in inner class reference to its outer class (when inner class is not static). Thanks to this field inner class instance has access to members (even private ones) of outer class instance.

Value of this field is set by `outerClassInstance.new InnerClass()` so `this$0` in `InnerClass` instance will contain same value as `outerClassInstance` reference.

You can't use this field directly in code like

```
class Outer{
    class Inner{
        void test(){
            System.out.println(this$0);//this will not compile
        }
    }
}
```

but you can access it via reflection. Code of method which will return value of this field could look like

```
public static Object getOuterInstance(Object inner)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException,
        IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    Class<?> clazz = inner.getClass();
    Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField("this$0");
    f.setAccessible(true);//in case of class placed in different package

    return f.get(inner);
}
```

Example:

```
class Outer {
    private String name;
    public Outer(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name; }

    class Inner{}
}

class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Outer o1 = new Outer("foo");
        Outer o2 = new Outer("bar");

        Inner i1 = o1.new Inner();
        Inner i2 = o2.new Inner();

        System.out.println(((Outer) getOuterInstance(i1)).getName());
        System.out.println(((Outer) getOuterInstance(i2)).getName());

    }

    public static Object getOuterInstance(Object inner)
            throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        Class<?> clazz = inner.getClass();
        Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField("this$0");
        f.setAccessible(true);

        return f.get(inner);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
```

which means that we did in fact get correct instances.

In case of your example you will have to:

1. iterate over each element in your `ite` iterator
2. use this method on each element from iterator
3. cast result of method to `Map` or if you need more precise type `LinkedHashMap`.